# how to read the instructions from pcie bus through mmio regions without actually copying them to the local dram?

Tags: linux-kernel, paging, cpu-cache, tlb, mips64

Is there a way to fetch the instructions from a target board's memory area(which is also a multicore processor) which is accessed through MMIO regions(through PCIe interface), without actually copying them to the host's local DRAM?

I tried to update the page tables with the MMIO address and jumped to that virtual address and also tried to jump directly to the MMIO address (PCI BASE + address on the target DRAM).
However, I am not able to step through the instructions using gdb(as i could see only nops) in both the cases.

Moreover, with the below print statement, I am able to see the hex code printed on the console. 
addr: (PCI BASE + DRAM Address of Target)

```
printf(" *** Reading:  0x%lx *** \n", *CASTPTR(volatile uint64_t, addr));
```

I am not sure whats going wrong, any pointers to the problem are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.